# Partitioning an ordered list of weights into N sub-lists of approximately equal weight

Tags: algorithm, partitioning

Suppose I have an ordered list of weights, having length M. I want to divide this list into N ordered non-empty sublists, where the sum of the weights in each sublist are as close to each other  as possible.  Finally, the length of the list will always be greater than or equal to the number of partitions.

For example:

A reader of epoch fantasy  wants to read the entire Wheel of Time series in N = 90 days.  She wants to read approximately the same amount of words each day, but she doesn't want to break a single chapter across two days.  Obviously, she also doesn't want to read it out of order either.  The series has a total of M chapters, and she has a list of the word counts in each.

What algorithm could she use to calculate the optimum reading schedule?

In this example, the weights probably won't vary much, but the algorithm I'm seeking should be general enough to handle weights that vary widely.

As for what I consider optimum, I would say that given the choice between having two or three partitions vary in weight a small amount from the average would be better than having one partition vary a lot.  Or in other words, She would rather have several days where she reads a few hundred more or fewer words than the average, if it means she can avoid having to read a thousand words more or fewer than the average, even once.  My thinking is to use something like this to compute the score of any given solution:

let W_1, W_2, W_3 ... w_N be the weights of each partition (calculated by simply summing the weights of its elements).
let x be the total weight of the list, divided by its length M.
Then the score would be the sum, where I goes from 1 to N of (X - w_i)^2

So, I think I know a way to score each solution.  The question is, what's the best way to minimize the score, other than brute force?

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: As hinted by the first entry under "Related" on the right column of this page, you are probably looking for a "minimum raggedness word wrap" algorithm.  Have you looked into that?

Comment: Also, the reason why someone downvoted you is probably because stackoverflow is more of a "what is wrong with my code" site and less of a "find me an algorithm" site.  Your question cannot really be turned into a "what is wrong with my code" question, but it can be made to look more like that type of question if you post code for a brute-force solution and ask us to help you with the pruning of the search tree.

Comment: Thanks @MikeNakis.  Your pointer to word wrap algorithms was just what I needed.  Looks like it's going to work for me.  If you'd care to turn this into an answer, I'd be happy to accept it. I ended up using something similar to the Knuth & Plass dynamic programming solution.

Comment: Well, I did not really do anything, I started thinking about your problem, and as I was thinking, my eyes wandered over the page, and then I saw the "related" link.  C-:=  But sure, let's not let this poor question go unanswered!  C-:=

Comment: @Aaron - you're welcome to answer your own question and accept it. If you can edit your own question to make your goals more clear, and describe how your answer addresses your goal, then this is encouraged equally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted by the first entry under "Related" on the right column of this page, you are probably looking for a "minimum raggedness word wrap" algorithm.

Comment: Comparing this post to the one you reference: the linked post seeks to minimize _m_ for a given _B_. It appears, using the terms of the linked post, that this OP seeks to minimize _B_ for a given _m_.

Comment: Well, if you read the comments under the question you will see that the OP found this answer useful, so who am I to argue?  Take it with him!

Comment: I saw that next :-) Nice find. Keeping this set of algorithms in my book of useful things, too.

Comment: Thank you.  I also found this tutorial helpful in wrapping my head around the basic idea: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RORuwHiblPc combined with your pointer, I was able to solve the issue.  It's not perfect, as it doesn't allow me to specify an exact number for N, but I can set an optimum length, and setting that to M/N gets me close enough. Also, when calculating the cost for all the combinations, I didn't reject any that were over the length, but simply scored them as the difference squared, as offsets are permissible in both directions, since we're not actually dealing with line lengths